# djangoCMS with Aldryn NewsBlog missing "New news/blog article"

Tags: python, django, blogs, django-cms

I am currently setting up a django CMS website on my server. I want to add a blog and tried to follow this [Divio Blog Guide](http://support.divio.com/academy/advanced-how-to-build-a-website-and-blog-with-django-cms/9-adding-news-blog), which works with the aldryn-newsblog plugin.
As I am not using the divio servers I had to install aldryn-newsblog. I  followed the [Aldryn Newsblog Setup](http://aldryn-newsblog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html):

`pip install aldryn-newsblog`

and added the following to my settings

```
'aldryn_apphooks_config',
'aldryn_categories',
'aldryn_common',
'aldryn_newsblog',
'aldryn_people',
'aldryn_reversion',
'aldryn_translation_tools',
'parler',
'sortedm2m',
'taggit',
```

I followed these last to steps from the Aldryn setup
1. Create a django CMS page in the normal way.
2. In Advanced settings... > Application settings, select NewsBlog.

When I select NewsBlog and try to "Create" a new News/Blog article I end up with this menu where i miss the corresponding button "New news/blog article". Did i forget or oversee something here?

[image: my menu with missing field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just faced the same issue – publishing the index page (page with a News & Blog apphook) should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on "example.com" > Administration... do you see this?

[image]

by clicking on "add", you can write an article (or at least a lead to an article); it will be then displayed on your created page according to your template. I hope this helps